# Localization/Validation - MVC C# model only taking my default resource file instead of my other language selected

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, resource-files

I am currently trying to get the validation from the backend models to the razor view using resource files. I have 2 languages setup, (en, fr) but even though French is selected, the error message is always in English.

I have tried multiple online tutorial / looking at other people having similar problem but none of the fixes worked for me.

my viewmodel example:

```cs
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredField", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(GlobalRes))]
[Display(Name = "Username", ResourceType = typeof(GlobalRes))]
public string Username { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredField", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(GlobalRes))]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password", ResourceType = typeof(GlobalRes))]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Razor view:

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "col-md-12" })
   <div class="col-md-12">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "form-control" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger"})
   </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-12" })
    <div class="col-md-12">
       @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     </div>
</div>
```

Inspecting the html in your browser after changing the language and submitting the form.

```html
<input class="input-validation-error form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Ce champ est requis." id="Username" name="Username" type="text" value="">
<span class="field-validation-error text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Username" data-valmsg-replace="true">This field is required.</span>

<input class="input-validation-error form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Ce champ est requis." id="Password" name="Password" type="password">
<span class="field-validation-error text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true">This field is required.</span>
```

What the expected results should be is, based on the language selected, the error message should be in french. If you inspect the input box, you can see the correct value being added in french. When submitting the form, you actually only get the english value instead of the expected one.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also but I find a simple way, I controller add this code.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{

}
else
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    TryValidateModel(Model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exactly same issue. For me putting the resource files in App_GlobalResources folder solved my problem!

If that folder does not exist already you can create it.

I am using localization on Asp.Net MVC application.